# why pandas dataframe intoroduces additional digits to columns names after reading them from excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet which contains data generated by running a program with different configurations. Two sample outputs are as follows. My first problem is `pd.read_excel()` introduces incremental digit suffices to the column names after the first group is read. For example the first dataframe has the correct column names **"A,B,C,D"** while the second dataframe has **"A.1,B.1,C.1,D.1"** and the third **"A.2,B.2,C.2,D.2"** and so on. How do I make sure that all have the same column names?

My data on excel

[image: My data on excel]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file_locn = ''r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\output.xlsx'''
df = pd.read_excel(file_locn, sheet_name='1', skiprows=1)
print(df)
df_256 = df[df.columns[0:5]]
df_128 = df[df.columns[6:11]]
df_64 = df[df.columns[12:17]]

print(df_256)
print(df_128)
print(df_64)
```

Output:

**print(df)**

[image: print(df)]

**print(df_256)**

[image: print(df_256)]

**print(df_128)**

[image: print(df_128)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If duplicated columns names pandas add `.Number` for create unique columns names.

Here is possible create `MultiIndex` in columns like:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_locn, sheet_name='1', header=[0,1])
```

And then use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), if first level is parsed like strings use:

```
df_256 = df.xs('256', axis=1, level=0)
df_128 = df.xs('128', axis=1, level=0)
df_64 = df.xs('64', axis=1, level=0)
```

If parsed like integers:

```
df_256 = df.xs(256, axis=1, level=0)
df_128 = df.xs(128, axis=1, level=0)
df_64 = df.xs(64, axis=1, level=0)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I am trying to plot these data in a 2X2 figure using the x-column as tick marks on the x-axis and in 2^n format where n ranges between 2 and 9. can you help please?

Comment: @hope - Not sue if understand well, it means 3 times ploting  like `df_256.set_index('X').plot(), df_128.set_index('X').plot(), df_64.set_index('X').plot()` ?

Comment: I think i should make this a separate question. I will post the link to the question here

Comment: Here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099479/figure-and-subplots-tick-labels-overlapping)